# How to execute a function in external file the name of which is stored in a string and also print the content of the file?

Tags: c++, function, variables, functional-programming, scope

**Goal:** *If I want to `cout` the source code of a function in an external `'.cpp'` before using it...*

**Question:** *How do I do that if the name of the function is stored in a string?*

---

I'm trying to `cout` the contents of the file and then ask the user if he's sure he wants to execute it...
If the user chooses to  execute the function, only then it'll be executed after `system(cls)`.

Here's the outline of the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>   /* Included all string related headers to play safe */
#include <cstring>  /* (I have no idea what these do...) ;P */
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "foo1.cpp"
#include "foo2.cpp"
#include "foo3.cpp"

using namespace std;
int exeFunc(string func){
    system("cls");
    func;   //call the function 'foo2()' from 'foo2.cpp'
}
int printFile(string prog){
    char ch;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open( prog.c_str() );   //this.cpp is the name of the current file
    while( !fin.eof() )
    {
        fin.read( (char*)&ch, sizeof(ch) );
        cout << ch;
    }
    return 0;
}

int selectProg(){
    int op;
    cout<<"Which Prog would you like to view?\nOptions:\n1\t2\t3 >> ";
    cin>>op;
    return op;
}

int main(){
    int p, a, e;
    p = selectProg();
    stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << "foo" << p << ".cpp";
    string prog = ss1.str();

    stringstream ss2;
    ss2 << "foo" << p << "();";
    string func = ss2.str();

    a = printFile(prog);
    e = exeFunc(func);

    return 0;

}
```

Content of all the `foo$.cpp` files, is of the form:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

foo1(){
    cout<<"Hello!! This is foo1 function!"<<endl;
}
```

---

I know my current code won't work as, the function `exeFunc()` isn't right.

```
int exeFunc(string func){
    func;   //call the function 'foo2()' from 'foo2.cpp'
}
```

How can I achieve this?? Any help/insight/alternate approach is appreciated...
Thanks...

Comment: No offense, but I think there is a big misconception here about how C++/compiled programs work... your cpp files are not some sort of "scripts" that you can execute on demand... You can of course print out the source code (provided the cpp files are available at runtime), but this will be of little use. Seems like you're having a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it that you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: You can't, basically.

Comment: @andreee Can I print out the source code of a particular function of the currently running program, if the user demands?? I only found the way to cout external files..when I was searching online, that's why I used that... your way will definitely be better... Can you help me write the exeFunc() to execute variable named function???

Comment: So there are actually C++ interpreters. [Cling](https://github.com/root-project/cling) for example. It can interpret strings of code.

Comment: You probably got a very different problem that you are trying to solve. _Why_ should the user print out the source code of a function? If you want this, you need to ship your code with the program in this case you could as well make it open source and in this case anyone could just look up the code in some repository if needed. So why do you bother with this? What is the reason you want this function?

Comment: @churill I am creating a Stand alone C++ program for my friends in college. They have 30 programs in total. So this master program will display the code of the user's choice first, and then give an option to execute it, if the user want to see the code in action... It's like a tutorial of sorts...

Comment: @churill You can check the project here... https://github.com/qrkz/cpp11

Comment: @YourPalNurav The easiest way is probably to write a mapping from function to file by hand. Or even easier (at least for you): provide only source code and let the user compile it themselves.